# How to customize sbt build command in intellij for spark

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, sbt

I need to add some profiles to the sbt command line: e.g.

```
sbt -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.5.2 assembly
```

So in Intellij 14 where is the sbt command line configured?